# Move a shed vs. Demolish and install a new shed

Tags: installation, remodeling, shed, demolition

We are remodeling and our current wooden shed needs to be moved to a new spot. One option is to hire folks to relocated the shed and the alternative is to demolish the current shed, dispose it and install a new one in the new spot. Looking for suggestion as what is more cost effective option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, this is to opinion-based for our Q&A format.

Comment: Depends on many factors - starting with the state of the current shed.

Answer (score 1):

How heavy is the shed? Depending on the size, say 12 x 12, you can move it using 2x4x or 4x4s easier than you think. You slide it right onto a foundation. Again this depends on how solid your shed is. In this area, anything with a side of 10 feet has to be permitted, so we just moved ours using above technique. Look at floor joists, and point loads of the current set up and match that up on the new.

Then again, a new shed is a chance to start over...

Comment: Check with your local zoning and environmental agencies to see if you _can_  move the shed's location.